# why is UIKit drawing not accelorated by using the graphics processor 'directly'

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, opengl-es

you hear a lot about the advantages of OpenGL using the graphics processor directly and that that is the main advantage of using this technology over UIKit for example. But, if it's so much better to do it this way, why does UIKit not do it also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a few more comments to what Steven wrote:

Every drawing on OS X and iOS is eventually done by Open GL. But there are ways drawing of a line can be done:

1. one is to render a line into a rasterized image by CPU, and then send the resulting rasterized image to the GPU to show it.
2. Another is to send the drawing command to the GPU so that the GPU draws it to a rasterized image.

Then, blending, animation etc work on the resulting rasterized image in the GPU.

If you use Open GL manually, 2. is what you usually do. I'm not sure which way UIKit drawing like `UIBezierPath` takes, but the OS X counterpart, AppKit, uses the method 1 unless you opt-in, which is called Quartz GL (which was called Quartz 2d extreme in the past):

1. Usually, AppKit draws things down to rasterized image, and send it to GPU.
2. With Quartz GL turned on, AppKit sends the drawing commands to GPU.

But Quartz GL is not turned on by default, due to various technical reasons, which are detailed in the (always fantastic) Ars Technica articles by John Siracusa. See the discussions [here for 10.4](http://arstechnica.com/apple/reviews/2005/04/macosx-10-4.ars/14) and [another for 10.5](http://arstechnica.com/apple/reviews/2007/10/mac-os-x-10-5.ars/9).

Here is one official documentation on [Quartz GL](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1536/_index.html).

Answer (score 7):

UIKit builds on CoreAnimation which builds on OpenGL. Ever wondered who's doing all that scaling and alpha blending for you? It's the GPU, through OpenGL textures that contain rendered images of your views.

By the way, I think this is one of Apple's great technical achievements. Think about how smooth the experience is (for a developer as well as the user) and how much work it would take you do achieve something remotely similar.

Comment: OK, thanks! So, I wonder how much faster a framework like cocos2d (which is an objective c wrapper for opneGL) is than using UIKit. I believe it's supposed to be faster. If so, I'd still have to ask a similar question... why don't apple do it also?

Comment: This is exactly right. You may be getting confused with Android. Up until Honeycomb, large amounts of the Android UI (and apps using the standard drawing/UI tools) weren't hardware accelerated. This is one reason why Android (particularly during its earlier versions) was generally a little more sluggish than iOS. iOS is using the GPU for the vast majority of its UI, and it really shows. The entire UI is, in fact, rendered and composited in 3D space by the GPU. Google some Core Animation demos if you don't believe it.

Comment: Don't know about Cocos, but UIKit/CoreAnimation is aimed at making smooth UI development easier, not about maxing out fill rate and vertices per second. Different objectives...

Comment: I find it hard to believe that choppy table scrolling animation with UIKit should be a thing of marvel.

Comment: Mmmmaybe for a homebrew, one-off, internal solution. Compare iOS with other UI frameworks, though, and you might think differently.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having problems finding documentation to back up my assertion, but I believe the stack is something like:

UIKit -> Core Graphics -> Quartz2D -> OpenGL

So, UIKit, is in fact making use of OpenGL to accelerate UI widgets.